# Removing/Adding XML child nodes through code

Tags: apex, xml

Does anyone have any idea on how to remove/add child nodes to an XML through apex code?

For example, i have an XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BookTitle>
<Book Title="1st Book"> Book1</Book >
<Book Title="2nd Book"> Book2</Book >
</BookTitle>
```

Here, i want to add/remove ' `<Book Title="3r Book"> Book3</Book >`' dynamically.

Any thoughts or helpful links will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and safe way to manipulate XML in Apex is through the [DOM implementation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_document) that is provided. (Trying to manipulate XML or JSON using string methods results in fragile code.)

This code illustrates how to use the DOM for your case:

```
@isTest
private class DomTest {

    @isTest
    static void test() {

        String xml = ''
                + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
                + '<BookTitle>'
                + '<Book Title="1st Book"> Book1</Book >'
                + '<Book Title="2nd Book"> Book2</Book >'
                + '</BookTitle>'
                ;

        // Parses XML
        Dom.Document doc = new DOM.Document();
        doc.load(xml);

        // Remove an element
        for (Dom.XmlNode child : doc.getRootElement().getChildren()) {
            if (child.getAttribute('Title', null) == '2nd Book') {
                child.getParent().removeChild(child);
            }
        }

        // Add an element
        Dom.XmlNode addition = doc.getRootElement().addChildElement('Book', null, null);
        addition.setAttribute('Title', '3rd Book');
        addition.addTextNode('3rd Book');

        System.assertEquals(
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><BookTitle><Book Title="1st Book"> Book1</Book><Book Title="3rd Book">3rd Book</Book></BookTitle>',
                doc.toXmlString()
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keith C. Can u plz share on how to assign the updated XML value (either after adding/deleting) to a variable..

Comment: Your instructions will gives a boolean value whether true or false but it doesn't give updated value @Keith C

Comment: For the remove case the `child` variable is the removed [XmlNode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm). For the add case `addition` us the added XmlNode.